# ESlint - Parsing error: Unexpected token for class private function

Tags: babeljs, eslint, eslintrc, eslintignore

I got `Parsing error: Unexpected token` for below class's _processMessage (private function). i am using babel and eslint ("babel-eslint",
    "babel-cli",
    "babel-core",
    "babel-preset-env",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports",
    "eslint",
    "eslint-config-google").

Error is 
`6:9  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token _processMessage`

```
class MyWorker {
  constructor(c) {
    super(c);
  }

  async _processMessage(message) {
    console.log(message);
    await someFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's being worked on for the next release: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10752. Btw which plugin are you using?